# nodejs&couchbase work with multi-core cpu and multi-server

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I use nodejs(access couchbase on the same server) setting up an online game server.
Now there are few users.
Just wonder if users become more and more.
It needs multi server/multi nodejs thread(on different cpu core)/multi couchbase, how can they cooperate together?
how to deploy the system?
Does any person have experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation of multiserver couchbase cluster is easy as a pie - just install couchbase on new server and add it to cluster with one button.

Nodejs scaling is more difficult. If you have realtime game (i.e. you use websockets to handle players communication) you should look to nosql databases that have "pub-sub" out of the box (i.e. [redis](http://redis.io/)). There are some utils that implement "pub-sub" for memcached, but they are very ugly and their performance isn't good. But if your game isn't realtime (i.e. your game is like FarmVille) you can use couchbase as a "shared" layer between nodejs threads and servers.